# Ошибка развертывания Rails на Heroku. Непонятная ситуация с гемами 'sqlite3' и 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Когда делаю "$ git push heroku master", в консоли появляется ошибка, говорящая о том, что Хероку использует postgres, а не sqlite. Погуглил, смысл ошибки понятен — у меня прописан гем sqlite. Исправил ситуацию, заменив его на 'pg', сделал 'bundle install', гем установился. Но при попытке снова развернуть приложение появляется все та же ошибка.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'heroku'
gem 'pg'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'sqlite3'
# end

# group :production do
#   gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
# end
```

Консоль:

```
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117/117), 24.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 117 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing rake 11.2.2
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160711-321-gshs8u.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.6.3
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing rake 11.2.2
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160711-321-gshs8u.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_66b483b49802dda58b0fa65c507dcaf2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.6.3
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to mysterious-crag-21552.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-crag-21552.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-crag-21552.git'
```

Я подозреваю, что подтягиваются гемы откуда-то из другого места, но я только начал изучать RoR и самостоятельно разобраться с этим не могу.

Comment: А что у вас написано в config/database.yml? adapter какой указан postgresql?

Comment: *Сделал `bundle install`*, а получившиеся `Gemfile` и `Gemfile.lock` закоммитили?

Comment: @cheops

`default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3`

Comment: @D-side

Похоже, что не закоммитил.

Comment: Что в результате? Починилось?

Comment: Да, я психанул и решил заново создать тестовое приложение с коммитами и все заработало с первого раза.